# Делаю пробный клиент/серверный проект на TCP протоколе. Не получается подключиться к серверу

Tags: c++, сеть, tcp, winsock

Делаю пробный клиент/серверный проект на TCP протоколе. Не получается подключиться к серверу. WSAGetLastError выдаёт такую ошибку:

Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.

Сервер:

```
void NetworkInitialization(CMaybeChatDlg* pDlg)
{
WSADATA wsadata;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata) != 0) {
    pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Initialization failed\r\n");
    WSACleanup();
}
else pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Initalization success\r\n");

TcpNP->socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (TcpNP->socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Creae socket failed\r\n");
    WSACleanup();
}
else pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Creae socket success\r\n");

TcpNP->addr.sin_port = htons(8523);
TcpNP->addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
TcpNP->addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

if (bind(TcpNP->socket, (sockaddr*)&TcpNP->addr, 
    sizeof(TcpNP->addr))==SOCKET_ERROR) {
    pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Bind socket error\r\n");
    closesocket(TcpNP->socket);
    int n = WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
}
else pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Bind socket csuccess\r\n");

if (listen(TcpNP->socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Set listen error\r\n");
    closesocket(TcpNP->socket);
    int n = WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
}
else pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Server wait connections\r\n");

struct ThreadParams {
    CMaybeChatDlg* pDlg;
};

ThreadParams* TP = new ThreadParams();
TP->pDlg = pDlg;



CWinThread* AcceptThread = AfxBeginThread((AFX_THREADPROC)AcceptClients, pDlg);
AcceptThread->ResumeThread();


}


void AcceptClients(CMaybeChatDlg* pDlg) {

CWinThread* WaitThread = AfxBeginThread((AFX_THREADPROC)WaitClient, pDlg);
WaitThread->ResumeThread();

int addrLen = sizeof(TcpNP->addr);

SOCKET clientSocket;
while (true) {
    clientSocket = accept(TcpNP->socket, (sockaddr*)&TcpNP->addr,&addrLen);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Accept client error\r\n");
        closesocket(TcpNP->socket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    else {
        pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Clent accepted\r\n");
        pDlg->m_WaitIndikator.ReplaceSel(L"Connected\r\n");
        wait = 7;
    }
}  
}

void WaitClient(CMaybeChatDlg* pDlg) {
while (wait != 7) {
    Sleep(250); pDlg->m_WaitIndikator.SetWindowText(L"Wait\r\n");
    Sleep(250); pDlg->m_WaitIndikator.SetWindowText(L"Wait.\r\n");
    Sleep(250); pDlg->m_WaitIndikator.SetWindowText(L"Wait..\r\n");
    Sleep(250); pDlg->m_WaitIndikator.SetWindowText(L"Wait...\r\n");
} 
pDlg->m_WaitIndikator.SetWindowText(L"Waited!\r\n");
ExitThread(0);
}
```

Клиент:

```
NetworkParams* NP = new NetworkParams;
void NetworkInitialization(CChaChaChatDlg* pDlg)
{
WSADATA wsadata;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata) != 0) {
    pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Initialization failed\r\n");
    WSACleanup();
}
else pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Initalization success\r\n");

NP->socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (NP->socket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Create socket failed\r\n");
    WSACleanup();
}
else pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Create socket success\r\n");

NP->addr.sin_port = htons(8523);
NP->addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1", &NP->addr);
NP->addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
int errorCode = WSAGetLastError();
LPWSTR errorBuffer = nullptr;

FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    nullptr,
    errorCode,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPWSTR)&errorBuffer, 0, nullptr);

if (errorBuffer != nullptr) {
    CString errorMessage(errorBuffer);
    pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(errorMessage);
}
if (connect(NP->socket, (sockaddr*)&NP->addr, sizeof(NP->addr))==SOCKET_ERROR) {
    int errorCode = WSAGetLastError();
    LPWSTR errorBuffer = nullptr;

    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
        nullptr,
        errorCode,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPWSTR)&errorBuffer, 0, nullptr);

    if (errorBuffer != nullptr) {
        CString errorMessage(errorBuffer);
        pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(errorMessage);
    }

} else pDlg->m_SystemInfo.ReplaceSel(L"Connection success");
}
```

Comment: Как минимум клиент ломится не на тот порт, на котором слушает сервер.

Comment: А, ой, это я забыл поменять когда публиковал XD. Но один шыш даже на верном порту он не может достучаться

Comment: дальше надо разрешить правильный порт в фаерволе *(брандмауэр)* на сервере. В дополнительных параметрах куча разрешений надо поставить.

Comment: команда `NP->addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1", &NP->addr);` портит память и переписывает структуру  `NP->addr`. Эта функция возвращает 1 или 0. И присваивание в `s_addr` не имеет смысла. Скорее всего нужно так : `unsigned char buf[sizeof(struct in6_addr)]; if (inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1", &buf))...; else error ;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Отключить ошибку которая запрещает использовать функцию inet_addr

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
```

И вместо:

```
NP->addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1", &NP->addr)
```

Использовать:

```
NP->addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: `#pragma warning(disable` служит для подавления ложных срабатываний предупреждений. В вопросе о появлении предупреждений в коде не упоминалось. А даже если они и были, то их надо исправлять, а не подавлять.